# Emulation.setGeolocationOverride not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to change my selenium location using `Emulation.setGeolocationOverride` but it didn't change no matter what I did:

```
import time

import undetected_chromedriver as uc

if __name__ == '__main__':

    options = uc.ChromeOptions()

    driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=False, options=options)


    driver.execute_cdp_cmd(
        "Emulation.setGeolocationOverride",
        {
            "latitude": 47.1111,
            "longitude": -122.1111,
            "accuracy": 90
        },
    )


    driver.get('https://www.google.com/maps')
    time.sleep(1231)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must now set permissions for the origin/domain to allow `geolocation` before setting the location.

Here's a full script that grants `geolocation` permissions to https://www.openstreetmap.org/, and then sets the location before navigating to that site:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.execute_cdp_cmd(
    "Browser.grantPermissions",
    {
        "origin": "https://www.openstreetmap.org/",
        "permissions": ["geolocation"],
    },
)
driver.execute_cdp_cmd(
    "Emulation.setGeolocationOverride",
    {
        "latitude": 48.87645,
        "longitude": 2.26340,
        "accuracy": 100,
    },
)
driver.get("https://www.openstreetmap.org/")
driver.find_element("css selector", "span.geolocate").click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Note that Google Maps tracks your location by IP Address, so changing geolocation might not help you on that specific website.

Comment: thanks, it works while searching normally, but I need to refresh the page once. Is it possible to update the location information without refreshing the page?

Comment: After calling `execute_cdp_cmd()`, the next `driver.get()` call will have the change.

Comment: `driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=apple&oq=apple")` you can test using this code location does not change on first search but if you refresh the page it will change

Comment: That's odd that a page refresh changes it, but Google generally uses an IP Address to calculate geolocation anyway. Instead of a page refresh, perhaps another `driver.get()` call would keep the settings you want.